# Sync Web Service automatically in android

Tags: android

My Name is Arivalagan and i'm stuck in one concept,i want to use auto sync in my android application,web service synchronization will happen automatically,can any one give the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with autosync? Depending on that, you can use:

- timer or alarm to launch events (polling)
- an android service to run sync processes in background (polling)
- push notifications to sync on demand